# How to copy a file from one site collection to another site collection using JSOM ,in a Sharepoint Hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, jsom

I have to create a sharepoint hosted app (Office 365) for copying a latest version of a file from one site collection to another site collection under the same tenant, using JSOM. Can someone direct me to the right solution?

Comment: You need to first perform read operation and then create operation. Please follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_FileTasks)

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_FileTasks)

```
function readFile(sourceSiteUrl,targetSiteUrl) {
    var clientContext;
    var oWebsite;
    var fileUrl;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, sourceSiteUrl).get_web();

    clientContext.load(oWebsite);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        fileUrl = oWebsite.get_serverRelativeUrl() +
            "/Lists/Shared Documents/TextFile1.txt";
        $.ajax({
            url: fileUrl,
            type: "GET"
        })
            .done(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler))
            .error(Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));
    }, errorHandler);

    function successHandler(data) {
        createFile(data,targetSiteUrl);
    }

    function errorHandler() {
        alert("Request failed: " + arguments[2]);
    }
}

function createFile(data,targetSiteUrl) {
    var clientContext;
    var oWebsite;
    var oList;
    var fileCreateInfo;
    var fileContent;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, targetSiteUrl).get_web();
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Shared Documents");

    fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
    fileCreateInfo.set_url("my new file.txt");
    fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());
    fileContent = data;

    for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {

        fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(fileContent.charCodeAt(i));
    }

    this.newFile = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);

    clientContext.load(this.newFile);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
    );

    function successHandler() {
       //success
    }

    function errorHandler() {
        alert("Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());
    }
}

//calling
readFile('url of source site','url of target site');
```